# Defender tamper protection off on Windows Server

Tags: windows

I am investigating a ticket that Virus & threat protection and App & browser control are now disabled on some servers in our network.

[image]

They want me to check why it happened and how to prevent this in the future.
I tried to check in event log / security if there is event id 1121 but unfortunately the log is too short and contains only last 2 hours of events, so I didn't find anything.

My question is how these two controls can deactivate - if it must be some admin user who disables them via this control panel or there are other things which can do it? I could enable it back just fine. There is no GPO controlling this. I was asked to check other servers if there is the same situation, so this I will have to do yet. I found these commands that can show it:

```
Get-MpPreference|select PUAProtection
Get-MpComputerStatus|select IsTamperProtected
```

I will probably make an Ansible playbook to check the rest of our servers with those.

So far I have seen it on Windows Server 2022 only, so maybe something related to this version...

Comment: is there a GPO to force these controls on and prevent users from switching it in Windows Security GUI? I didn't find it...

Comment: Any update on this , I am also facing the same thing on all Windows Server 2022 boxes